# Целое изображение в ImageButton при изменении ее размеров

Tags: android, android-layout

Здравствуйте! Как изменить размер ImageButton и при этом сохранить целую картинку, помещенную в эту кнопку? Поместил imagebutton на экран, добавил туда картинку размером 125*125 пикселей но кнопка стала занимать пол экрана. Тут же сжать ее нельзя, а в .xml коде стоят эти параметры:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Как можно решить эту проблему сохранив целую картинку? Пробовал заменять параметры на 125px или 125dp, но картинка срезалась.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Установите для кнопки необходимые размеры и задайте `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Ну и если необходимо, ужмите картинку.

Answer (score 2):

А если что-нибудь из этого попробовать?

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/X"
            android:layout_width="Xdp"
            android:layout_height="Xdp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@null"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если кнопка квадратная и её размер необходимо изменять в зависимости от устройства 
    **android:scaleType="fitCenter"**
Вписать изображение кнопки в начале 
**android:scaleType="fitStart"**
Вписать изображение кнопки в конце 
**android:scaleType="fitEnd"**